# Counting a subset in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I got a simple xml about movies it follows like this:

```html
<movies>
 
 <!-- 1 -->
    <movie>      
        <movieID>0108052</movieID>     
      
        <title>Schindler's List</title>
      
        <director>Steven Spielberg</director>  
  
        <year>1993</year>
      
        <genre>Biography, Drama, History</genre>
  
  <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/</link>
    </movie>
    
 <!-- 2 -->
    <movie>      
        <movieID>0914798</movieID>     
      
        <title>The Boy in the Striped Pajamas</title>
      
        <director>Mark Herman</director>  
  
        <year>2008</year>
      
        <genre>Drama, War, History</genre>

  <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0914798/</link>  
    </movie>

</movies>
```

Now I got some tables made depending on which year the movies fall on. And at the end I wanted to add an extra footer row saying how many movies were made on that year. I used this code:

```html
<td>Number of Movies: <xsl:value-of select="count(movies/movie)"/> </td>
```

But that only gives me all the movies in the xml, Is there any way I can limit it to movies done in say after 2004? I was thinking to perhaps count the number rows in the table if that is possible and performing arithmetic, but I don't know if xslt can do that.

I create the tables using this:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
    <!-- Sort by title -->
      <xsl:sort select="title"/>
   <xsl:if test="year>=2005">
   
   <tr bgcolor="#3D9999">
   
     <td>
      <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
                <a href="{link}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>
              </td>
     
              <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
     </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="movieID"/>
              </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I don't know about per year, but for 2004+ you could do `<xsl:value-of select="count(movies/movie[year>=2004])"/>`

Comment: @Kenney  That certainly works, but it seems to be one off, no big deal manually corrected it. Submit this as the answer so I can give you the well deserve recognition.

Comment: If you want the movies made after 2004, use `[year>2004]`, not `[year>=2004]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the expression to count a subset like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(movies/movie[year>=2005])"/>
```

Outputting the number of movies per year can be done by grouping using the `key` function for XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="movie_year" match="movie" use="year" />

  <xsl:template match="movies">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th># movies</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="movie[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('movie_year', year))]">
        <xsl:variable name='this' select="."/>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="count(../movie[year=$this/year])"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```